# Change image hide status while UITableView is in edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This might be simple question. I have a UITableView and each cell contains a UIImageView. What I want to achieve is

```
if(is under the editing mode)//Hide UIImageView
if(not in the editing mode)//Show UIImageView
```

I tried to use tag to access those UIImageView, but no luck. The main trick for me is how to access those images.

How can you do this?Using tags?Parent View?
Many Thanks : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying other ways, I use viewWithTag method for it and it is working : ) Basically, I start tag from 100 as I know there is no more than 20 views in one page in my case.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
UIImageView *checkMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"]];
checkMark.frame = CGRectMake(xx, xx, xx, xx);
checkMark.hidden = YES;
checkMark.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
```

And then I can access all my images using

```
for (int i = 100; i < [self.vehiclesArray count] + 100; i++) {
   ((UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i]).hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UITableView and override the method

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

then you can put your if else block inside.

PS: Do not forget to call the method of super class

You can hide and show images by setting the hidden property of image view.eg.

```
imageView.hidden = YES;
```

You can define the images in your header file and then they are accessible in every method of your class.

Comment: I know how to turn on the editing mode, the question is how to show and hide UIImagesView.

Comment: Yes, but how can you access those images? I have a Edit button in the navigation bar. When I click that button, I want to access all the images and set hide YES.

Comment: Yes, I can add UIImageView in the header file. But I can only add one?(I did it, but it can only affect one uiimageview) What if there are many UIImageView in the table?Can we make it dynamic? I tried tags, but there is no even trigger like uibuttonview, I cannot access those images...

Comment: add them in an array and set tag attribute, then you can use - (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag method to get which one you want.

Comment: I have just seen that you had been updated you question. So your images are in cells? if so then you need to change them in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I mean your if else block and in your set editing method you need to call reloadData method.

Comment: it is common courtesy to accept an answer if any of the 3 posts were correct in helping you solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the image views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the condition that you are editing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...

    if (self.editing)
      imageView.hidden = YES;

...
}
```

then reload the table view when editing is set:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to access all your tableView cells and hide the imageView. But this is not possible, as your cells are (if implemented correctly) reused, and so the amount of cells might be less than the number of rows in your tableview.

That is why you need to set everything regarding the cells appearance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I have many imageViews, not only one. I want to make it dynamic(The number is depends on database, and database is changing all the time), so can not fix the number of images. How can we do that?

Comment: I did it successfully now. I use viewWithTag for accessing those images. I set it from 100, as I know there is no more than 100 tag in my page. And then you can access every images : )